# C# A nested array initializer is expected, build 3dimensional array using a 2dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, syntax-error

From a function I am receiving a 2 dimensional array, I want to use this array as input data to my neural network. For this to be working it has to be an element of a 3-dimensional array. When I try to do this I get an error. I'm probably doing something wrong syntax-wise but can't figure out what the solution is. Can anyone help me?

```
int[,] d = image.GetData();
int[,,] neuralInput = { { d } };
```

also tried:

```
int[,,] neuralInput = { d };
bool[] answers = new bool[1] { true };
```

which both result in this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0846  A nested array initializer is expected  Sandbox C:\Users\Jordy\Documents\KBS-SE3_VR- 
Rehabilitation-Data\Sandbox\Program.cs  47  Active
```

and:

```
int[,] d = image.GetData();
int[,,] neuralInput;
neuralInput[0] = d;
```

which results in:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0022  Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 3   Sandbox C:\Users\Jordy\Documents\KBS- 
SE3_VR-Rehabilitation-Data\Sandbox\Program.cs   47  Active
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every element of an `int[,,]` is an `int` - they're independent elements. It looks like what you're trying to build is an `int[][,]` - an array where each element is an `int[,]`. If you genuinely need an `int[,,]`, you'll need to create one of the right size, and copy elements from your `int[,]` into it. It's *possible* that `Buffer.BlockCopy` or similar would do that, but I'd probably just write a loop... something like this:

```cs
public int[,,] Project2DInto3D(int[,] source)
{
    int cols = source.GetLength(0);
    int rows = source.GetLength(1);
    int[,,] ret = new int[1, cols, rows];
    for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            ret[0, x, y] = source[x, y];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Full example:

```cs
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[,] original = { { 5, 3 }, { 2, 1 }, { 8, 3 } };
        Console.WriteLine("Original:");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{j}, {k}] = {original[j, k]}");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        var projected = Project2DInto3D(original);
        Console.WriteLine("Projected:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"[{i}, {j}, {k}] = {projected[i, j, k]}");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static int[,,] Project2DInto3D(int[,] source)
    {
        int cols = source.GetLength(0);
        int rows = source.GetLength(1);
        int[,,] ret = new int[1, cols, rows];
        for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
            {
                ret[0, x, y] = source[x, y];
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Original:
[0, 0] = 5
[0, 1] = 3
[1, 0] = 2
[1, 1] = 1
[2, 0] = 8
[2, 1] = 3

Projected:
[0, 0, 0] = 5
[0, 0, 1] = 3
[0, 1, 0] = 2
[0, 1, 1] = 1
[0, 2, 0] = 8
[0, 2, 1] = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You've attempted to provide array initializers for both a single dimensional:

```
int[,,] neuralInput = { d }; // states 3 dimensions, initialized as one, invalid.
```

and two dimensional:

```
int[,,] neuralInput = { { d } };  // states 3 dimensions, (almost) initialized as two, invalid.
```

but no three dimensional:

```
int[, ,] array3D = new int[,,] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
```

more:

[Multidimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

There are differences in C# between **jagged** and multi-dimensional arrays. The jagged arrays are arrays in arrays, and can be declared like that:

```cs
int[][] jagged2d = new int[][];
```

Jagged arrays are arrays in arrays. If you used a jagged array, it would work. You can set one of its inner arrays.

However, "simple" multi-dimensional arrays aren't meant to modify a full array inside them; you can only modify or get exactly one value at a time.

For more information, refer to [jagged arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) and [multidimensional arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays).